# Create a character selection screen with LibGDX

Tags: java, dynamic, textures, libgdx

I am still in the process of studying LibGDX. I am trying to create a character selection screen, wherein the player can choose a character and when he/she clicks its picture (for example: a button) of his/her chosen character, the displayed texture changes. So it´s like a dynamic texture. Where should I begin?

Comment: You should begin by studying LibGDX more. Read the documentation. Read the wiki. Read the code of the example projects. Read tutorials. Do it yourself. That's the only way to go. Nobody here has the wish to post you the code to every problem you come across. Show some effort please.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not really asking for code, I just want some ideas since there are a lot of ways to do stuff. There's no harm in that, I think. Thank you though.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, yes. But stackoverflow is not the correct place for such questions. It's a place for very concrete questions/problems and opinion based ones, like this one are usually closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of all those not really sufficient answers, I'll also provide one myself here.

Since this is a UI-specific task, like any menu/selection/options screen, you should read [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) and [scene2d.ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) first.

What you would do is creating a `Stage` and add a `Table` to it. To the table you could then add a `Button`/`ImageButton` with an arrow to the left (as text maybe just "<--"). You will also add a `ClickListener` to this button to be able to handle the character switch when the user clicks on that button. Then you add an `Image` to the table, its picture will depend on the selected character. Then you add a button with an arrow to the right just like the first button (with the listener as well).

I assume that you have a list of possible characters and their "avatars" which you want to display. With each click event (left or right) you will increment/decrement a list index which points to that list and switch the image of the `Image` to the correct character.

If you use `table.row()` you might also add another "apply" button to the table, so it will appear underneath the other elements. When this button is clicked, you know an index to a character and can switch to the next screen (probably your gameplay screen).

The picture of the middle element which shows the currently selected character will have to be updated in your `render()` method in every frame, because it might have changed.

Probably you also want to add some more information to the selected character to this screen, like a name, or special abilities. You can use some `Labels` for that and update them in each frame, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for character and have the texture as it's member which you would always use for drawing each character object.

Now clicking the buttons would only change the texture of the given character.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a number of [ImageButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html) for every character possibility with a ClickListener for each one, and an Image to represent the chosen character. When a user presses on a button, the listener sets the Drawable of the Image to the character selected.